# how to dynamically add columns to an already built row with reference to xml

Tags: android, dynamic, tablelayout, multiple-columns

I have been struggling with this problem from few days now have searched many forums along with this, but now am frustated to the core. :(

I am trying to build a table dynamically through code. I am successfuly able to add new columns new rows from the code withing a for loop.

I am doing it successfully through the code like:

```
                    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblCosts);
    for (int hi = 0; hi < 4; hi++ ) {       
            tr = new TableRow(this);
            tr.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                    LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

            // Create a text view to be the row-content.
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
                TextView tv = new TextView(this);
                tv.setText("Dummy data" + i);
                tv.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tv.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shape);
                tv.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                // Add text View to row.
                tr.addView(tv);

        }

        // Add row to TableLayout.
        tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    }
```

This gives me perfect 4X10 table to an already built table in the xml with some header rows.

However when I am trying to add few views dynamically to an already built row referenced from the xml my code is throwing an error "java.lang.IllegalStateException: The specified child already has a parent. You must call removeView() on the child's parent first.
"

Below is the code I am using

```
    TableLayout tl = (TableLayout) findViewById(R.id.tblCosts);

    // Create a new rows to be added.
    TableRow tr = (TableRow) findViewById(R.id.tRheadercost2);
            for (int hi = 0; hi < 4; hi++) {
                TextView tvname = new TextView(this);
                tvname.setText("Name"+hi);
                tvname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT,
                        LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                tvname.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(5+hi));
                tvname.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.shapegreywithborder);
                tvname.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                // Add text view to row.
                tr.addView(tvname);
            }
    tl.addView(tr, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Here I have already built a row R.id.tRheadercost2 in the xml with with a layout_span of 4 (5 columns). I want my code to dynamically add more columns in the same row after column 5.

here is a snippet of java xml:

```
                <TableRow android:id="@+id/tRheadercost2"
            android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content">
            <TextView android:textColor="#000" android:background="@drawable/shapegreywithborder"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" android:padding="5dp"
                android:text="" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_column="0" android:layout_span="4"></TextView>
        </TableRow>
```

Comment: Don't use random tags. `xcode` is iOS IDE. removed

Comment: Extremely sorry about that. wasn't intentional.

Comment: No problem. Just wanted to let you know in case you thought it means something else.